# Windows Mobile Recurring Appointment Types

Tags: windows-mobile, appointments

Currently I have a HTC Snap device running Windows Mobile 6.1.  It's a great phone thus far but one little snag confounds me, it's recurring pattern options in appointments are somewhat limited, for example I can't do "second tuesday of every month" or "1st wednesday of every month".  Is there any way to set up recurrences such as these, or do you know of a better appointment manager that can?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default apps on WM sucks so bad, you need this if you want to get serious on your PIM.

[Pocket Informant](http://www.pocketinformant.com/products_info.php?p_id=pocketinformant)

Comment: Great program!  Probably the only way you're gonna manage this.

Answer (score 1):

If it's the standard Windows Mobile calendar, those patterns should be feasible.

There are certainly patterns that Windows Mobile *can't* do (or at least, if it can do them it can't represent them in ActiveSync :) but these examples are okay.

For example, to get "second Tuesday of every month":

- Start creating the event
- Click on the "Occurs" drop down
- Select `< Edit pattern >`
- Select the duration and click "Next"
- Select "Monthly"
- Select the second radio button and edit the values to "second" and "Tuesday"
- Click Next and pick start/end dates
- Click Finish

That was performed on a Windows Mobile 6.1 PocketPC emulator. I've just tried on a SmartPhone emulator, and it looks like the calendar is more restricted there. However, I strongly suspect that it's still capable of representing that sort of event - just not editing it on the phone.

You could set your phone up to sync, e.g. with Google Calendar. You could then create the events in the more powerful application, and I'd at least *expect* them to be faithfully reproduced on the device. I should add that I'm biased towards the Google Calendar solution as I work on [Google Mobile Sync](http://www.google.com/mobile/products/sync.html#p=default), particularly the calendar part :)

Of course, syncing has numerous other benefits too...

Comment: Downvoters: please leave comments, otherwise your downvote is pointless.

Comment: Alright that downvote was me, given that your directions were out of tune with my mobile device and operating system, you appear to have no experience in what you were saying and I voted accordingly...

Comment: @tekiegreg: I wrote those instructions by going through them on a Windows Mobile emulator. I'm sorry it didn't tally with the version you've got - I suspect the SmartPhone calendar doesn't work exactly the same way as the PocketPC one. If it's really impossible that would be a shame. Will try on a SmartPhone emulator...

Comment: (In general it's still a good idea to leave a comment when you vote though. If you'd done so initially, I'd have investigated the difference between PocketPC and SmartPhone calendars immediately.)

Comment: Well I'll remove my down-vote, at least you tried with what you have and it would be irrational for me to expect every copy of windows mobile, possibly even every mobile phone make/model with the same operating system to work the same.  My apologies.